# How to remove if the row has same value in ajax search?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tour packages.
Many tour packages have the same destination / city.

I am trying to create a search box with ajax live search where user can search by destination/city.

Since many packages have the same destination/city when the user search for a city the same city name is shown multiple time according to tour packages.

let's say `tour pkg1, tour pkg2, tour pkg3` have the city NY.

When we put the **N** in the search field it shows NY **`THREE times`** but I want to show only once if the city is same.

mark up:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="skills">Skills: </label>
        <input id="skills">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'search.php'
        });
    });
</script>
```

search.php:

```
<?php
    //database configuration
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'mydb';

    //connect with the database
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    //get matched data from skills table
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tour_package WHERE fcity LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY fcity ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['fcity'];
    }

    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and the table :

[image]

How can I remove the same `fcity` is found for many `pkg`?

**EDIT**

If I use(distinct) `$query = $db->query("SELECT * distinct FROM tour_package WHERE fcity LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY fcity ASC");` 
live search does not work. when I type it shows nothing.

Comment: Serioulsly? You asked similar question already and I advised you to use `distinct`. What's the difference now?

Comment: no.. that was for another query.. I used that in dropdown list.. that works fine.  but if I use the same in `$query = $db->query("SELECT distinct* FROM tour_package WHERE fcity LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY fcity ASC");` still it shows the same values of the row. but it works fine in `$query = "select distinct fcity from tour_package";` `<option value="<?php echo $row['fcity']; ?>"><?php echo $row['fcity']; ?></option>`

Comment: You use only `fcity` field for your data. Why then do you use `select *`? Use query like `SELECT DISTINCT fcity FROM tour_package WHERE fcity LIKE %VALUE%`